# Azure AD how to expose API to users?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I followed a Microsoft tutorial on how to create an SPA and API and use MSAL to secure it (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api).

But they ask to expose the API like this:

For the Scope name, use Todolist.Read.
Select the Admins and Users options for Who can consent?.
For the Admin consent display name, type in scopeName.
For the Admin consent description, type in e.g. "Allows the app to read the signed-in user's files.".
For the User consent display name, type in scopeName.
For the User consent description, type in e.g. "Allows the app to read your files.".

However, I can't find where I can change the 'Who can consent?' options.

So, when I create a new scope, I can change the Admin scope name and description, but there's no 'Who can consent?' option available. [image: adding a new scope]

And when the scope is created, I can't change it either; it says "Admins only." [image: scope]

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you are exposing an API scope in **B2C tenant application** that does not include 'Who can consent?' option. Switch your directory to normal Azure AD tenant. If you want to call B2C api, follow this [doc](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/2-call-api-b2c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to **expose an API** scope in B2C tenant application, I also cannot find `Who can consent?` option:

[image]

You need to **switch your directory** to normal Azure AD tenant and make it as current directory like below:

[image]

In that Azure AD tenant, I registered one application named `msal-node-api` and **exposed an API scope** where I can see "Who can consent?" option:

[image]

Now, I created another app registration named `msal-react-spa` and added above **permissions** in it:

[image]

When I ran the **sample** following same document, I got below screen after successful authentication:

[image]